# Matrix not correctly transformed to shader

Tags: c#, hlsl, slimdx

In my application i have a problem with passing my world, view and projection matrix to the shader. I have set up a little engine to perform those tasks and i am using PIX and visual studio to debug what i get as output.

First i post the code that relates to the vertices and indices:

```
Rendering.Geometry.MeshGeometry<uint> geom = Rendering.Geometry.MeshGeometry<uint>.Create(device);
var elem = Rendering.Geometry.VertexElement.CreatePosition3D(device);
float[] vertices = new float[9]
{
    0, 0, -3,
    0, 0, 3,
    0, 5, 0,
};

elem.DataStream.WriteRange(vertices);
geom.AddVertexElement(elem);

var triangle = geom.Triangles.AddFace();
triangle.P1 = 0;
triangle.P2 = 1;
triangle.P3 = 2;
```

The geometry seems to be correct because when i debug my draw call in PIX i get the correct values for the vertices (0/0/-3)/(0/0/3)/(0/5/0) so i think index buffer, vertex buffer, input layout and polygon topology are all set up correctly.

Now in PIX i have that interesting Pre-VS, Post-VS view. Pre-VS as i told everything looks fine, the vertices are correct in the right order. When i go to Post-VS and debug a vertex i end up in my shader where i can go through the instructions.

Now what is not correct are the matrices passed to it with the constant buffer. Here is my shader:

```
cbuffer MatrixBuffer
{
    float4x4 worldMatrix;
    float4x4 viewMatrix;
    float4x4 projectionMatrix;
};

struct VertexInputType
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
};

struct PixelInputType
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
};

PixelInputType BasicEffectVS(VertexInputType input)
{
    PixelInputType output = (PixelInputType)0;

    float4x4 worldViewProj = worldMatrix * viewMatrix * projectionMatrix;

    output.position = mul(input.position, worldViewProj);   
    output.position.w = 1.0f;
    return output;
}
```

When i have a look in PIX for the three matrices i see that except for the worldMatrix they have completely wrong values (even NaN is contained) for viewMatrix and projectionMatrix. The way i set the matrices in my application is the following:

```
basicEffect.WorldMatrix = SlimDX.Matrix.Identity;
basicEffect.ViewMatrix = SlimDX.Matrix.Transpose(SlimDX.Matrix.LookAtLH(new SlimDX.Vector3(20, 5, 0), new SlimDX.Vector3(0, 5, 0), new SlimDX.Vector3(0, 1, 0)));
basicEffect.ProjectionMatrix = SlimDX.Matrix.Transpose(SlimDX.Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH((float)Math.PI / 4, ((float)f.ClientSize.Width / f.ClientSize.Height), 1.0f, 100.0f));
```

Debugging them in VS gives me the correct values. I then follow the SetValue call on the shader until i get to the actual writing of bytes. Everything is fine there!

The buffer is created the following way:

```
holder.buffer = new SlimDX.Direct3D11.Buffer(mShader.Device, new BufferDescription()
{
    BindFlags = BindFlags.ConstantBuffer,
    SizeInBytes = buffer.Description.Size,
    Usage = ResourceUsage.Dynamic,
    CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Write

});
```

Even worse:
If i add another matrix parameter to my shader and i set a hardcoded matrix for that value, like:

```
Matrix mat = new Matrix()
{
    M11 = 1,
    M12 = 2,
    ...
};
```

in PIX i get exactly the values i expect. So my function setting values to the shader must be right.

Anyone has an idea where this comes from?

Comment: Can you post your constant buffer construction code?

Comment: Sure, i have edited it into my posting!

Comment: TBH, I meant all the code relating to the constant buffers and those matrices ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove this line:
    output.position.w = 1.0f;

This is the projective component, since you already multiplied by your projection matrix you need to send it as it is to the pixel shader.

Also I would be quite careful with all the transposes, i'm not sure they are really needed.